# mysql client - select * minus a set of columns

Tags: mysql

When using the mysql client, I'm working on some tables that have like 10 columns plus 4 columns of meta information (created_at,created_at_utc, update_at, updated_at_utc - similar to rails). I'm trying to create a way to essentially do a select * minus these 4 sets of columns mostly to make it so that it fits in a single window without breaking the results. I'm leaning towards writing a stored procedure / program with the table name but wondering if there is a better way. something like:

```
 >call t($table_name)
```

Might there be a better way to do this? thx

edit:
so I'm not concerned about performance, I would use this only to verify things are being updated / inserted correctly.

Comment: I'm assuming your problem is that if you add a non-meta column you will have to rewrite your code, so you're looking for a solution to ignore those columns dynamically?

Comment: the issue isn't the rewriting of application code, just that any testing / verification / looking up of data gives me all this extra info that I'm not really interested in. I'm looking for something like a dynamic view (ie a filter) with these 4 predefined columns taken out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if it is select only, then you can make a view...

Comment: +1 You could also put the metadata in a separate table, but that would be more cumbersome to update.

Comment: I'm not really looking into a sol'n for getting data back to the app so views might be more cumbersome than the problem. I'm looking for an idea that is more like filter the select * and strip out these predefined columns in the result.

Comment: +1 for Randy. @tipone, how is this cumbersome? A view just let's you treat a `select a, b, c, d` as if it were a table in it's own right.

Comment: on the select side I'd agree that it isn't but you have to create views and then create a trigger so that the updates on that table get correctly propagated. perhaps it's writing a shell script that you run against a database with a set of tables that creates the views, strips out the unwanted meta-information and then also creates the associated triggers? It's almost easier (and a lot more proven) to just replicate it to write only version and filter the columns at that point.

Comment: ignore my above comment - haven't used views in a while and liking this idea better. python + describe statements should do it.

Answer (score 1):

There is no built-in way to achieve this.
You do better not to use `*` at all. This will slow down the query optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

There are two simple solutions that allow for the non-meta columns to grow without code modification or maintaining a view:

1. Documented naming convention: Prefix them all with say, `meta_` and do not display those columns. Downside: they are requested and part of the result set, hence more overhead.
2. Split meta columns into a separate table using 1:1 relationship and create a view for other applications / application paths to use. Downside: some overhead on each query for the 1:1 join.

Comment: re #1, how would I achieve this? The known columns are currently predefined so I don't think I would need the prepending. #2 is being done now already with a versioning system. There are some tables that are not versioned so we have redundancy with this other piece (similar to rails in syntax and the versions (?) gem)

Comment: @timpone Hmm, you're not coding your own client app, but using the "mysql client program"? Then you can't. Just dawned on me that you're trying to do this.